# Slanted TIPA text

Tags: texstudio, texshop, italic, tipa, slanted

I'm relatively new to LaTex, and am using it to write my linguistics thesis. I started out in TexShop. Although the TIPA faq says you can't use italics with TIPA, this seemed to be working fine. Now I've switched to Texstudio and it doesn't work. I've also tried slanted text, and this doesn't work either (I've also attempted this in ShareLatex). Can anyone help? I've tried many ways of combining macros, and many different macros for both italics and slanted text (e.g. \textsl, \slshape, \it, etc). Why does it work in TexShop and not the other compilers? Am I missing something?

---

**Minimal working example:**

```
\documentclass[twoside, 11pt, a4paper, footinclude=true, headinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tipa} 

\begin{document}

\textipa{\slshape tuFuN} \hspace{.65in} `sunset'


\end{document}
```

---

**results in:**

tuɸuŋ ‘sunset’

Comment: Honestly, what you're describing seems close to impossible.  So *this* document compiles with no errors in TeXShop (as it does for me) and also compiles with no errors in TeXStudio and the output is wrong?  Or does the file not compile with TeXStudio?

Comment: Since you're using TeXshop as the front-end, I assume you're using MacTeX as the back-end. On a system running MacOSX 10.9.2 and MacTeX2013, I can report that your MWE compiles fine using three different front-ends: TeXshop, TeXworks, and LaTeXian. Are you using TeXstudio on a non-Mac system?

Comment: And it compiles fine with TeXStudio on a Mac too, for me.

Comment: Wah, so apparently this DOES work in both TexShop an TexStudio (on a mac), but the same commands in my actual document doesn't come out slanted at all. Im wondering if there might be some kind of interaction with another package... No idea now, but thanks for your help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non reproducible problem